# AjaxUpload, передать параметр динамически

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Модуль для импорта файла в опенкарте.
Таким способом загружается файл и посылает его в контроллер.

```
new AjaxUpload('#button-upload', {
  action: 'index.php?route=module/related_options/import&token=<?php echo $token; ?>',
  name: 'file',
  autoSubmit: true,
  responseType: 'text',
    data: {
        check : $("#check_id").val(),
    },
 // params: { check: 1 }
  onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
      $('#button-upload').after('<img src="view/image/loading.gif" class="loading" style="padding-left: 5px;" />');
  },
  onComplete: function(file, result) {

    $('.loading').remove();

    $('#import_result_text').html("<?php echo $entry_server_response; ?>: "+result);

    json = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
    if (json['error']) {
      $('#import_result_text').html('Error: '+json['error']);
    } else {
      $('#import_result_text').html('<?php echo $entry_import_result; ?>: '+json['products']+'/'+json['relatedoptions']);
    }
  }
});
```

Вместе с ним, мне нужно передать дополнительное значение -

```
 data: {
        check : $("#check_id").val(),
    },
```

Проблема в том, что это значение формируется динамически, и не подхватывает значение, когда оно поменялось. Каким образом можно добавить динамическое значение в AjaxUpload ??

Answer (score 0):

Через keyup должно работать. Вставляешь переменную:

```js
$('#check_id').keyup(function(){
var check_id = $('#check_id').val();
});
```

И используешь ее:

```js
data: {
check : check_id,
},
```